# How can I modify my css layout to merge two cells together?

Tags: html, css

So far I have the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mko2qqay/) and as you can see there are 8 pictures (that are links) in the following layout:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

I would like to combine 1 and 2 together to display there one picture (width of it would be combined of 2 single images), so instead of 1 and 2 I want to have X centered. Basically like this:

```
  X   3  4
5  6  7  8
```

How can I modify my fiddle to make it so? I know I have to remove the first picture from HTML. But how can I modify CSS?

```css
/* ==========================================================================
Screenshots
========================================================================== */
.screenshots ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.screenshots ul li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #000;
    list-style: none;
}
.screenshots figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.screenshots figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figure:hover img, .screenshots figure:focus img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.screenshots figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25% 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(63, 97, 132, 0.85);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figcaption a {
    color: #fff
}
.screenshots figcaption a:hover, .screenshots figcaption a:focus {
    color: #73d0da
}
.screenshots figure:hover figcaption, .screenshots figure:focus figcaption {
    opacity: 1
}
.visible {
    opacity: 1
}
.screenshots figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1
}
.screenshots figcaption i {
    font-size: 35px
}
.screenshots figcaption p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.screenshots figcaption .caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.screenshots figure:hover figcaption .caption-content, .screenshots figure:focus figcaption .caption-content {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<section class="screenshots" id="screenshots">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <ul class="grid">
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/01.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Optimised For Design</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/02.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>User Centric Design</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/03.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Responsive and Adaptive</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/04.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Absolutely Free</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <ul class="grid">
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/05.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Multi-Purpose Design</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/06.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Exclusive to Codrops</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/07.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>Made with Love</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
       <figure>
        <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
        <figcaption>
        <div class="caption-content">
         <a href="img/large/08.jpg" class="single_image">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i><br>
          <p>In Sydney, Australia</p>
         </a>
        </div>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: css can't really affect the structure of the page, only how it's displayed. if you want your two "cells" to be combined into a single one, css at most could hide one and stretch the other. you'd need JS to rejigger the DOM tree to eliminate one cell otherwise.

Comment: Short of adding padding to either side of that one image, you could try putting the images in a table and make the first cell twice the width.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest if you put the pictures inside a border-less table, with the first and second column of the first row span each other. Formatting tables with CSS is much easier. 
Something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
      <figcaption>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.sugarpet.net/oscar.jpg" alt="Screenshot 01">
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I actually didn't get the solution you propose, could you give me some example?

Comment: ok, i've updated my answer to give you an idea what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the HTML you could do something like this:

```
.screenshots .row:first-child ul li:first-child{
    display:none;
}
.screenshots .row:first-child ul li:nth-child(2){
    width:50%;
}
.screenshots figure img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mko2qqay/4/). The main limitation is the `max-height: 70px;` on the image tag.

If you can remove the first `<li>` of the first `ul.grid` then just remove the `nth-child(2)` style and update the `first-child` selector by removing `display:none;` and adding `width:50%`.

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me why did you put `max-height: 70px;` here? now my pictures are really small...

Comment: @randomuser1 You can remove the `max-height` and give your img's a `height` of 100%, but then you may need to give a height to your `<ul>` or `<li>`'s